# EmbeddedForm symfony saving

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm experiencing a problem to solve the newly added "Prix" in my Soiree Form

I've embedded the PRixForm in my SoireeForm and i'm using ajax calls to add as many prix as we want.

The problem is, when I want to add a new PRix by clicking on the "+" and after filling my fields nothing is saved... 
When i'm editing or filling the first default embedded form prix it works which is weird. Only those added by ajax are not saved..

Here is my code

in my form, SoireeForm:

```
public function addNewPrix($number){

      $new_prix = new BaseForm();


        for($i=0; $i <= $number; $i+=1){

            $pri = new Prix();
            $pri->setSoiree($this->getObject());
            $prix_form = new PrixForm($pri);    
            $new_prix ->embedForm($i, $prix_form);

        }

        $this->embedForm('new', $new_prix);
    }

    public function saveEmbeddedForm($con = null, $forms = null){

            $dataForms = $this->getEmbeddedForm('new')->getEmbeddedForms();

                foreach ($dataForms as $dataForm)
                    $dataForm->getObject()->setSoiree($this->getObject());

                parent::saveEmbeddedForm($con, $forms);


      }
```

In my action:

```
public function executeAdd($request)
    {
      $this->forward404unless($request->isXmlHttpRequest());
      $number = intval($request->getParameter("num"));

      $this->form = new SoireeForm();

      $this->form->addNewPrix($number);

      return $this->renderPartial('addPri',array('form' => $this->form, 'num' => $number));
    }
```

my partial addPri:

```
<li>

 <?php echo $form['new'][$num]['titre']->renderLabel();?>
 <?php echo $form['new'][$num]['titre']->render()?>

 <?php echo $form['new'][$num]['montant']->renderLabel();?>
 <?php echo $form['new'][$num]['montant']->render();?>
 <br />
 <br />
```

and my prix.js file:

```
newfieldscount = 0;


function addPri(num) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/backend_dev.php/soiree/add?num='+num,
    async: false
  }).responseText;

};


var removeNew = function(){
  $('.removenew').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
  })
};

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#add_prix').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("ul#extraprix").append(addPri(newfieldscount));
  newfieldscount = newfieldscount + 1;
  $('.removenew').unbind('click');
  removeNew();
});
```

});

I guess the problem comes from my saveEmbed method in my form, but i don't understand why or how to make everything work as it should.

Thank you in advance you guys

Comment: This is not about programming embedded systems.  Retagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want save an 1:n relation, so you should find everything you need here

- http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/stretching-sfform-with-dynamic-elements-ajax-a-love-story
- http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms

If not, please provide information or code of your PrixForm->configure() function !

PS: Your saveEmbeddedForm() function is unneeded, you'll find more information about the form saving process in the second link in chapter 6 !

Comment: thank you so much i'll look into that ! my prixform->configure only has  unset($this[ 'soiree_id']); in it.